# What is a causal structure?

Tags: general-relativity, causality, topology

The notion of "causal structure" brings up many different notions in general relativity.

- It is associated with the fiber bundle $\pi : \mathcal{C} \to M$ set of every light cone at every point of spacetime[[1]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012635250X)
- It is the assignment of signs to vectors in the tangent bundle ("bare-causality"), and if we deal with time orientation, it will additionally orient causal vectors towards the past or future.[[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.00986)
- It corresponds to specific subsets of the projectivized tangent bundle $S \subset \mathbb{P}TM$, oriented or not [depending on whether we want to consider one or two cones], with some eventual conditions on $S$ such as strong convexity and a well-behavied Hessian
- It is an equivalence of vector fields [g] such that for every $X$, $\mathrm{sgn}(g(X,X)) = \mathrm{sgn}(g'(X,X))$
- There is quite a lot of theory about it involving the use of Finsler metrics
- It is a parabolic Cartan geometry, either $(D_n, P_{1,2})$, $(B_{n-1}, P_{1,2})$ or $(D_3, P_{1,2,3})$, with a flag variety as a homogeneous space. [[6]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02542)
- It's a double fibration between the cone structure, the space of null geodesics and the manifold, $\mathrm{N} \leftarrow \mathcal{C} \to M$, or alternatively, $J^2(\mathbb{R}) \leftarrow J^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \to M$ [[5]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02542)
- It is defined by the null geodesic spray [[4]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5254)
- It is related to the space of null geodesics [3][5](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528401)
- It is defined by the null twistors, which are also flags in their own right

There are many possibly incompatible definition of this (and possibly wrong, I am not perfect), and a lot is written by either physicists or mathematicians with little middle ground, so that it can be tough to separate everything.

My main questions on the topic are :

- Is there a fundamental difference between the conformal structure and the causal structure? I would think so, since beyond the causality, the conformal structure also encodes the angular data of the tangent bundle.
- How important is the null flag in all of this, does it define the entire null cone? There seems to be many tricks to get the null flag to be as small as possible, but at its core it seems to involve a null curve running along the light cone, as well as a tangent hyperplane to the light cone. Given just those two objects, and ignoring possible other structures such as the conformal and metric structure, is it possible to reconstruct the entire light cone from those data? Either by some kind of geometric construction, or at least by using that flag to determine the causal characteristic of any vector of $TM$. Also importantly, would this reconstruct *any* type of light cone, since the general theory can allow for them not to even be quadrics?

There are a lot more objects purported to define or help construct the causal structure, such as the projective Hilbert form, bracket-generating distributions, and so forth, but that's about all I could manage so far.

Comment: Slereah: _"[...] "causal structure" brings up many different notions in GR."_ -- Certainly. However, the notions explicitly listed in your OP seem to be exclusively concerned with "causal structure" in GR **as a topic of differential geometry**. In addition, I'd like to draw attention to notions in GR which represent "causal structure" as the entirety of causal relations which are attributed to each pair of (distinct) events of any spacetime region under consideration $p, q \in \mathcal S, p \not\equiv q$; namely as : $$ \text{either "timelike", or "lightlike", or "spacelike"} $$. Either ...

Comment: ... **(1)** as a topic in the **geometry of (suitably generalized) metric spaces**.
 
$$\text{timelike}[ \, p, q \, ] \Longleftrightarrow ((\ell[ \, p, q \, ] \ne 0) \text{ or } (\ell[ \, q, p \, ] \ne 0)) $$

where $\ell : \mathcal S \times \mathcal S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ denotes [Lorentzian distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lorentzian+distance%22+%22stackexchange%22),

Comment: $\text{lightlike}[\,p,q\,]\Longleftrightarrow\\ ((\ell[\,p,q\,]=0)\text{ and }(\ell[\,q,p\,]=0)\text{ and}\\ \qquad ((\exists\, a\in\mathcal S\,|\,((\ell[\,a,p\,]\ne 0)\text{ and }(\ell[\,a,q\,]\ne 0))\text{ and}\\ \qquad\qquad (\forall\, j\in\mathcal S\,|\,((\ell[\,a,j\,]\ne 0)\text{ and }(\ell[\,j,p\,]\ne 0))\implies (\ell[\,j,q\,]\ne 0)))\text{ or}\\ \qquad ((\exists\, b\in\mathcal S\,|\,((\ell[\,q,b\,]\ne 0)\text{ and }(\ell[\,p,b\,]\ne 0))\text{ and}\\ \qquad\qquad (\forall\, k\in\mathcal S\,|\,((\ell[\,k,b\,]\ne 0)\text{ and }(\ell[\,q,k\,]\ne 0))\implies (\ell[\,p,j\,]\ne 0))))))$, and

Comment: otherwise $\text{spacelike}[\,p,q\,]$. $$\, $$
Or **(2) "operational"**:$$\text{timelike}[\,p,q\,]\Longleftrightarrow\exists\, A\in\mathcal P\,|\,((p\in A)\text{ and }(q\in A))$$where $A$ is a "path" (of an actual or imaginable "material point"); and otherwise further distinction between pairs of events being $ \text{either "lightlike", or "spacelike"} $ related to each other derives through the notion ["unreachable set" (of a path, wrt. an event that doesn't belong to it)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unreachable%22+%22John+W+Schutz%22); and the thereby definable notion "signal front".